# How to properly configure access to kubernetes dashboard behind nginx ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to configure nginx ingress to access several services, like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-monit
spec:
  rules:
  - host: grafana.localhost
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: prometheus-grafana
          servicePort: 80
  - host: kubernetes-dashboard.localhost
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: kubernetes-dashboard
          servicePort: 80
```

I've access to the grafana service without any problems, my issue is with kubernetes-dashboard.
I've already configured kubernetes-dashboard to allow HTTP traffic with this configuration

```yaml
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: monit
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 9090
  selector:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard

---

kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: monit
spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: kubernetes-dashboard
          image: kubernetesui/dashboard:v2.0.0-beta8
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9090
              protocol: TCP
          args:
            - --namespace=monit
            - --insecure-bind-address=0.0.0.0
            - --insecure-port=9090
            - --enable-insecure-login
            # Uncomment the following line to manually specify Kubernetes API server Host
            # If not specified, Dashboard will attempt to auto discover the API server and connect
            # to it. Uncomment only if the default does not work.
            # - --apiserver-host=http://my-address:port
          volumeMounts:
            - name: kubernetes-dashboard-certs
              mountPath: /certs
              # Create on-disk volume to store exec logs
            - mountPath: /tmp
              name: tmp-volume
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              scheme: HTTP
              path: /
              port: 9090
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            timeoutSeconds: 30
          securityContext:
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
            readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
            runAsUser: 1001
            runAsGroup: 2001
      volumes:
        - name: kubernetes-dashboard-certs
          secret:
            secretName: kubernetes-dashboard-certs
        - name: tmp-volume
          emptyDir: {}
      serviceAccountName: kubernetes-dashboard
      nodeSelector:
        "beta.kubernetes.io/os": linux
      # Comment the following tolerations if Dashboard must not be deployed on master
      tolerations:
        - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
          effect: NoSchedule
```

I;ve also a valid token which I can use to access kubernetes dashboard when I use ClusterIP.
However when I access it through ngress I cannot go over the login page even with valid token (see screenshot).

[image]

I looked into Nginx logs for problems/errors but everything seemed fine

```sh
$ kubectl logs -n monit ingress-nginx-controller-bbdc786b4-6nl9h  -f
192.168.65.3 - - [03/Jun/2020:02:03:13 +0000] "GET /api/v1/csrftoken/login HTTP/1.1" 200 85 "http://kubernetes-dashboard.localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36" 479 0.001 [monit-kubernetes-dashboard-80] [] 10.1.0.123:9090 85 0.001 200 59fc952888dfadf0223740c31e562ef8
192.168.65.3 - - [03/Jun/2020:02:03:13 +0000] "POST /api/v1/login HTTP/1.1" 200 1508 "http://kubernetes-dashboard.localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36" 1545 0.005 [monit-kubernetes-dashboard-80] [] 10.1.0.123:9090 1508 0.005 200 241388246b11031765557475bea603ff
192.168.65.3 - - [03/Jun/2020:02:03:13 +0000] "GET /api/v1/plugin/config HTTP/1.1" 200 185 "http://kubernetes-dashboard.localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36" 477 0.003 [monit-kubernetes-dashboard-80] [] 10.1.0.123:9090 185 0.003 200 45371469793ce4f35c45dec70530bea0
192.168.65.3 - - [03/Jun/2020:02:03:13 +0000] "GET /api/v1/login/status HTTP/1.1" 200 108 "http://kubernetes-dashboard.localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36" 476 0.001 [monit-kubernetes-dashboard-80] [] 10.1.0.123:9090 108 0.001 200 49171f5e9316a2d6da883d1c4f0b50df
192.168.65.3 - - [03/Jun/2020:02:03:13 +0000] "GET /api/v1/login/status HTTP/1.1" 200 108 "http://kubernetes-dashboard.localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36" 476 0.001 [monit-kubernetes-dashboard-80] [] 10.1.0.123:9090 108 0.001 200 c69b9d166f1527f00e7cd175696ec8c7
192.168.65.3 - - [03/Jun/2020:02:03:13 +0000] "GET /api/v1/login/status HTTP/1.1" 200 108 "http://kubernetes-dashboard.localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36" 476 0.001 [monit-kubernetes-dashboard-80] [] 10.1.0.123:9090 108 0.001 200 1f9c27ca407bca57dcc0c26bca65be58
```

What am I missing in my ingress configuration?

**UPDATE:** I tried to setup an https ingress for the dashboard with this config

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: https-ingress-monit
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: kubernetes-dashboard.localhost
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: kubernetes-dashboard
          servicePort: 443
```

But this does not seem to work, no endpoint is configured

```
$ kubectl describe ingress https-ingress-monit -n monit
Name:             https-ingress-monit
Namespace:        monit
Address:          localhost
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
Rules:
  Host                            Path  Backends
  ----                            ----  --------
  kubernetes-dashboard.localhost  
                                  /   kubernetes-dashboard:443 (<error: endpoints "kubernetes-dashboard" not found>)
Annotations:                      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age   From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----  ----                      -------
  Normal  CREATE  87s   nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress monit/https-ingress-monit
  Normal  UPDATE  74s   nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress monit/https-ingress-monit
```

Now when I try to access http://kubernetes-dashboard.localhost/ I see `503 Service Temporarily Unavailable`

Comment: It looks like you cannot login by the lack of HTTPS. Please take a look here: [Github.com: Kubernetes: Dashboard: Login not available](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/tree/master/docs/user/accessing-dashboard#login-not-available) and here [Stackoverflow: Accessing Kubernetes Dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60281374/accessing-kubernetes-dashboard/60378005#60378005). You will need to reconfigure your `Ingress` resource. Please let me know the results.

Comment: thanks for the links, I don't have an error message like the one described in https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/tree/master/docs/user/accessing-dashboard#login-not-available. In fact, nothing happens when I click sign in

Comment: Does this means that when exposing the dashboard on a URL like http://kubernetes-dashboard.localhost it just won;t work and I have to configure another ingress rule for https?

Comment: Yes, please try to configure your `Ingress` resource to support `HTTPS` and let me know if it helped.

Comment: @DawidKruk I tried with https for communication between Nginx and dashboard service. see updated post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### **TL;DR**

**You cannot pass the verification (pressing `Sign In` doing nothing) by the lack of `HTTPS`.**

As I said in the comment:

> ### Login not available
>
> If your login view displays below error, this means that you are trying to log in  over HTTP and it has been disabled for the security reasons.
>
> Logging in is available only if URL used to access Dashboard starts with:
>
> - `http://localhost/...`
> - `http://127.0.0.1/...`
> - **`https://<domain_name>/...`**
>
> *[Github.com: Kubernetes: Dashboard: Login not available](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/tree/master/docs/user/accessing-dashboard#login-not-available)*

You can login to `Kubernetes Dashboard` **without HTTPS** only with:

- `http://localhost/...`
- `http://127.0.0.1/...`

**You need `HTTPS` to login to your `Kubernetes Dashboard` with:**

- `https://IP.ADDRESS`
- `https://DOMAIN.NAME`

---

### **`endpoints "kubernetes-dashboard" not found`**

> But this does not seem to work, no endpoint is configured

**It means that the `Ingress` resource could not find the `Endpoint` to sent the traffic to. This happened in your case because:**

- `Ingress` is in `default` namespace
- `Service` named `kubernetes-dashboard` is in `monit` namespace

To make it work you can (one of the ways) make another `Ingress` resource specifically in `monit` namespace.

You can invoke below commands to get more information about your resources:

- `$ kubectl get services -n monit`
- `$ kubectl get endpoints -n monit`

Resources in Kubernetes are strictly connected to `namespaces`. You can read about them more here: [Kubernetes.io: Concepts: Working with objects: Namespaces](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/)

---

You have several ways to deploy `Kubernetes Dashboard`. It will depend on the solution you are using (`minikube`,`bare metal kubeadm cluster`,`eks`,`gke`, etc.).

General steps to take to deploy `Kubernetes Dashboard` with `Nginx-ingress`:

- Deploy `Nginx-ingress`
- Download and modify the `Dashboard` definition
- Configure access to `Dashboard` with `Ingress`
- Test it

#### Deploy `Nginx-ingress`

Please follow official documentation regarding deployment of `Nginx-ingress`: [Kubernetes.github.io: Ingress-nginx: Deploy](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/)

#### Download and modify the `Dashboard` definition

Installation of Kubernetes `Dashboard`: [Kubernetes.io: Web ui dashboard: Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/#deploying-the-dashboard-ui)

Above link can be used to deploy `Dashboard` but few adjustments will need to be made.

Assume the following:

- Every resource in `kubernetes-dashboard` namespace
- Arguments for `Dashboard`:

  > ```
  >   - args:
  >     - --namespace=kubernetes-dashboard
  >     - --enable-insecure-login
  >     - --insecure-bind-address=0.0.0.0
  > ```
- `Dashboard` listening on port `9090`
- `Services` as well as healthchecks associated with `Dashboard` set to port `9090/TCP/HTTP`.

> A tip for arguments!
>
> **enable-skip-login false**   When enabled, the skip button on the login page will be shown.
>
> *[Github.com: Kubernetes: Dashboard: Arguments](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/common/dashboard-arguments.md#dashboard-arguments)*

Your Dashboard definition will need a `Service` to be exposed outside the cluster. You can create your own definition of a `Service` like example below or edit definition included in installation `YAML` above.

Example below:

```yaml
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: dashboard-service
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  selector:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 9090
      nodePort: 30001
      name: dashboard-port
  type: NodePort
```

Please take a specific look on part:

```yaml
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 9090
      nodePort: 30001
      name: dashboard-port
```

Traffic will be sent to the `Dashboard` pod on port `9090` as required by the  arguments of the `Dashboard` itself.

#### Configure access to `Dashboard` with `Ingress`

Assuming your `Ingress` is deployed correctly you can use below example to expose `Dashboard`:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dashboard-ingress
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: tls-secret # NON-EXISTENT
  rules:
  - host:
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: dashboard-service
          servicePort: dashboard-port
```

Please take specific look on parts:

- **`- secretName: tls-secret # NON-EXISTENT` - it will configure controller to use a fake certificate and allow `HTTPS` connections**
- `namespace: kubernetes-dashboard` - namespace is exactly the same as other `Dashboard` resources
- `serviceName: dashboard-service` - name of the service associated with `Dashboard`
- `servicePort: dashboard-port` - name of the port of the service associated with `Dashboard`

#### Test it

After this steps you should be able to enter either ip address or domain name to your web browser and open `Dashboard` panel.

**Please make sure that you connect to `Dashboard` with: `https://`.**

If you configured your `Dashboard` to require authentication you should provide the authentication token. You can find your token by invoking below command:

- `$ kubectl describe secret NAME_OF_THE_SECRET -n NAMESPACE`

Comment: this is outstanding, thanks for the details pointer, that answers lot of my questions all at once!!