# How to solve error 503 in Kubernetes NGINX Ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to access Kubernetes Dashboard using NGINX INGRESS but for some reason I'm getting a 503 error.

I'm running Kubernetes locally in my macbook with docker desktop.

First thing I did was apply/install NGINX INGRESS CONTROLLER

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.47.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
```

Second thing I did was to apply/install kubernetes dashboard YML File

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.2.0/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml
```

Third Step was to apply the ingress service

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dashboard-ingress
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |-
      proxy_ssl_server_name on;
      proxy_ssl_name $host;
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: /
            backend:
              service:
                name: kubernetes-dashboard
                port:
                  number: 433
```

When I try to access http://localhost and/or https://localhost I get a 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable Error from nginx

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is part of the log from the NGINX POD

```
I0630 23:36:42.049398      10 main.go:112] "successfully validated configuration, accepting" ingress="dashboard-ingress/kubernetes-dashboard"
I0630 23:36:42.055306      10 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"kubernetes-dashboard", Name:"dashboard-ingress", UID:"85e7bd9e-308d-4848-8b70-4a3591415464", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"47868", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'Sync' Scheduled for sync
I0630 23:36:42.056435      10 controller.go:146] "Configuration changes detected, backend reload required"
I0630 23:36:42.124850      10 controller.go:163] "Backend successfully reloaded"
I0630 23:36:42.125333      10 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller-5b74bc9868-gplcq", UID:"bbd70716-b843-403b-a8f9-2add0f63f63f", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"46315", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
192.168.65.3 - - [30/Jun/2021:23:36:44 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 54 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36" 657 0.003 [kubernetes-dashboard-kubernetes-dashboard-80] [] 10.1.0.25:8443 48 0.002 400 395aec46af3b21e79cd650f2f86722f3
2021/06/30 23:36:44 [error] 1222#1222: *17477 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while sending to client, client: 192.168.65.3, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.1.0.25:8443/", host: "localhost"
2021/06/30 23:36:45 [error] 1222#1222: *17512 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while sending to client, client: 192.168.65.3, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.1.0.25:8443/", host: "localhost"
192.168.65.3 - - [30/Jun/2021:23:36:45 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 54 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36" 657 0.002 [kubernetes-dashboard-kubernetes-dashboard-80] [] 10.1.0.25:8443 48 0.001 400 a15e1e48987948cb93503b494d188654
2021/07/01 00:09:31 [error] 1224#1224: *49299 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading upstream, client: 192.168.65.3, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.1.0.25:8443/", host: "localhost"
192.168.65.3 - - [01/Jul/2021:00:09:31 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 54 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36" 657 0.002 [kubernetes-dashboard-kubernetes-dashboard-80] [] 10.1.0.25:8443 48 0.001 400 ac6b88ca52b73358c39371cb4422761d
2021/07/01 00:09:32 [error] 1221#1221: *49336 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while sending to client, client: 192.168.65.3, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.1.0.25:8443/", host: "localhost"
192.168.65.3 - - [01/Jul/2021:00:09:32 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 54 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36" 657 0.001 [kubernetes-dashboard-kubernetes-dashboard-80] [] 10.1.0.25:8443 48 0.001 400 2c5cd2d9403a8e50a77fdc897c694792
2021/07/01 00:09:33 [error] 1221#1221: *49338 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while sending to client, client: 192.168.65.3, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.1.0.25:8443/", host: "localhost"
192.168.65.3 - - [01/Jul/2021:00:09:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 54 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36" 657 0.001 [kubernetes-dashboard-kubernetes-dashboard-80] [] 10.1.0.25:8443 48 0.000 400 f1f630c886d20b9b9c59bd9e0e0e3860
2021/07/01 00:09:33 [error] 1224#1224: *49344 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading upstream, client: 192.168.65.3, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.1.0.25:8443/", host: "localhost"
192.168.65.3 - - [01/Jul/2021:00:09:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 54 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36" 657 0.001 [kubernetes-dashboard-kubernetes-dashboard-80] [] 10.1.0.25:8443 48 0.001 400 2ab6774dec6e2a89599c4745d24b9661
192.168.65.3 - - [01/Jul/2021:00:09:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 54 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36" 657 0.001 [kubernetes-dashboard-kubernetes-dashboard-80] [] 10.1.0.25:8443 48 0.000 400 c9147e08203d9ec8e7b0d0debab8d556
2021/07/01 00:09:33 [error] 1222#1222: *49360 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while sending to client, client: 192.168.65.3, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.1.0.25:8443/", host: "localhost"
I0701 00:10:19.024220      10 main.go:112] "successfully validated configuration, accepting" ingress="dashboard-ingress/kubernetes-dashboard"
I0701 00:10:19.026772      10 controller.go:146] "Configuration changes detected, backend reload required"
I0701 00:10:19.027392      10 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"kubernetes-dashboard", Name:"dashboard-ingress", UID:"85e7bd9e-308d-4848-8b70-4a3591415464", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"50637", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'Sync' Scheduled for sync
I0701 00:10:19.102759      10 controller.go:163] "Backend successfully reloaded"
I0701 00:10:19.103246      10 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller-5b74bc9868-gplcq", UID:"bbd70716-b843-403b-a8f9-2add0f63f63f", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"46315", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
192.168.65.3 - - [01/Jul/2021:00:11:27 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 592 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36" 657 0.000 [kubernetes-dashboard-kubernetes-dashboard-433] [] - - - - c449f6e8082761ddc3432f956f4701f2
192.168.65.3 - - [01/Jul/2021:00:11:29 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 592 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36" 657 0.000 [kubernetes-dashboard-kubernetes-dashboard-433] [] - - - - 3a41974b01c5e63e734fce6e37b98e4c
192.168.65.3 - - [01/Jul/2021:00:11:56 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 503 592 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36" 408 0.000 [kubernetes-dashboard-kubernetes-dashboard-433] [] - - - - c01f7bec83d3be6b26703b8808f9922a
192.168.65.3 - - [01/Jul/2021:00:11:58 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 503 592 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36" 24 0.000 [kubernetes-dashboard-kubernetes-dashboard-433] [] - - - - dc39bcddd4ecfdefe931bf16fe3c1557
192.168.65.3 - - [01/Jul/2021:00:16:36 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 190 "-" "curl/7.64.1" 73 0.000 [kubernetes-dashboard-kubernetes-dashboard-433] [] - - - - 82aad4321afbccb3fc54ac75d96b66ee
192.168.65.3 - - [01/Jul/2021:00:31:47 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 503 592 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36" 417 0.000 [kubernetes-dashboard-kubernetes-dashboard-433] [] - - - - c4ab3d2f272be4d38df62c0ffd50bfe9
I0701 00:48:02.059067      10 main.go:112] "successfully validated configuration, accepting" ingress="dashboard-ingress/kubernetes-dashboard"
I0701 00:48:02.062292      10 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"kubernetes-dashboard", Name:"dashboard-ingress", UID:"85e7bd9e-308d-4848-8b70-4a3591415464", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"53737", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'Sync' Scheduled for sync
I0701 00:48:02.062876      10 controller.go:146] "Configuration changes detected, backend reload required"
I0701 00:48:02.131494      10 controller.go:163] "Backend successfully reloaded"
I0701 00:48:02.131787      10 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller-5b74bc9868-gplcq", UID:"bbd70716-b843-403b-a8f9-2add0f63f63f", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"46315", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
192.168.65.3 - - [01/Jul/2021:00:48:12 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 503 592 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36" 417 0.000 [kubernetes-dashboard-kubernetes-dashboard-433] [] - - - - d50e3bb0db3a5fa7581c405b8c50d5c8
192.168.65.3 - - [01/Jul/2021:00:48:14 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 503 592 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36" 15 0.000 [kubernetes-dashboard-kubernetes-dashboard-433] [] - - - - c8d8752fb4d79d5bc084839ef9a767b2
I0701 00:49:50.908720      10 main.go:112] "successfully validated configuration, accepting" ingress="dashboard-ingress/kubernetes-dashboard"
I0701 00:49:50.911044      10 controller.go:146] "Configuration changes detected, backend reload required"
I0701 00:49:50.911350      10 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"kubernetes-dashboard", Name:"dashboard-ingress", UID:"85e7bd9e-308d-4848-8b70-4a3591415464", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"53896", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'Sync' Scheduled for sync
I0701 00:49:50.979935      10 controller.go:163] "Backend successfully reloaded"
I0701 00:49:50.980213      10 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller-5b74bc9868-gplcq", UID:"bbd70716-b843-403b-a8f9-2add0f63f63f", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"46315", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
192.168.65.3 - - [01/Jul/2021:00:50:55 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 503 592 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36" 417 0.000 [kubernetes-dashboard-kubernetes-dashboard-433] [] - - - - d62a8012bc23bbc35a47621d54d68a62
192.168.65.3 - - [01/Jul/2021:00:51:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 503 592 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36" 15 0.000 [kubernetes-dashboard-kubernetes-dashboard-433] [] - - - - 0cbfd2274ad687fc1aaff76dbc483659
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've reproduced this setup and encountered the same issue as described in the question:

- `503 Service Temporarily Unavailable Error`

Focusing specifically on this setup, to fix above error you will need to modify the part of your `Ingress` manifest:

- from:

```yaml
                name: kubernetes-dashboard
                port:
                  number: 433
```

- to:

```yaml
                name: kubernetes-dashboard
                port:
                  number: 443 # <-- HERE!
```

You've encountered the 503 error as `nginx` was sending a request to a port that was not hosting the dashboard (`433` -> `443`).

After that change, I was fortunate enough to see the Dashboard login page.

I'd also recommend you following a guide to create a user that could connect to the dashboard with it's bearer token:

- *[Github.com: Kubernetes: Dashboard: Docs: User: Access control: Creating sample user](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/user/access-control/creating-sample-user.md)*

---

Additional resources:

- *[Serverfault.com: Questions: How to properly configure access to kubernees dashboard behind nginx ingress](https://serverfault.com/a/1020468/545585)*

Comment: Unbelievable, thanks a million for catching that typo! You saved me a lot of headaches!.. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

from the official doc,

`It's important the file generated is named auth (actually - that the secret has a key data.auth), otherwise the ingress-controller returns a 503`

which means the secret need have a `auth` key